# Drop Down Navigation box has a width for two columns of text. How do I make a style to give it a width for one column AND a width for two columns?

Tags: css

**HTML, this is a short piece of the list**

```
        <div id="navigation"><div id="navHorizCont">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">CAMP</a>
    <ul class="listhieght">
    <li><table width="200"  cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="link">Tents</a></td>
    <td><a href="link">Books</a></td>
  </tr> 
    </table>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
      </ul>
```

**CSS this is the style for the box that goes around the two columns of text**

```
    #products {
    background-color: #0F0;
    width: 750px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-image: url(images/product_background.gif);
    background-position: center 1px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: please provide relevant html code.

Comment: Post some relevant css, the code you have now does not say anything about your menu.